# Why the Style tag is not working properly in HTML?

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm creating a webpage from scratch and I'm running into a problem

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #ppp {
      font-style=italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="ppp">Italic</p>
  <b Style="color:red">red bold</b></br>
  some text
</body>

</html>
```

The text "Italic" should be italic, but is not

Comment: Because thats not valid CSS.

Comment: try to replace "=" with " : "

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

<style>
#ppp{
     font-style : italic;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="ppp">Italic</p>
    <b style="color:red">red bold</b>
    <br>
    some text
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The '=' sign that you have used (in `font-style=italic;`) is not the proper syntax; you have to use colon ':' instead of that.

That will most probably fix your code, if all you want is to print in Italics.

Answer (score 2):

Th issue is that your Css is not valid
It should be

`font-style: italic;` with a **":"**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #ppp {
      font-style:italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="ppp">Italic</p>
  <b style="color:red">red bold</b></br>
<p>some text<p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you'r css to this:

```css
font-style: italic;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #ppp {
      font-style=italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="ppp">Italic</p>
  <b Style="color:red">red bold</b></br>
  some text
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <html>

<head>
  <style>
    #ppp {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="ppp">Italic</p>
  <b Style="color:red">red bold</b></br>
  some text
</body>

</html>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Using the  tag, that tag must be inside the  tag. Using inline style, that tag must be inside an HTML element, for example: Megan McMullin .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).